# "Factorizing" a sum of GLMs

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, actuarial-science

I was looking a little bit into insurance mathematics, which left me puzzling about a question. I'll give you some context first:

When estimating the total claim amount for, say, a motor insurance, it is very common to use GLMs to model the expected costs. A standard way to go is the following:

1. Build a GLM with a Poisson distribution and a log link function to
   model the claim frequency (i.e. estimate how many claims you'll see
   within 1 year)
2. Build a GLM with a Gamma distribution and also a log link function to model the claim severity (i.e. estimate what is the average claim amount)

Because a log link allows you to express the desired quantity as a product of the form
$$
E[Y] = exp(\beta_1 x_1) \cdot exp(\beta_2 x_2) \dots,
$$
you can identify a multiplicative factor $exp(\beta_i)$ associated with each coefficient. (Here the  $\beta_i$ are the coefficients of the GLM and $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is the, for simplicity binary, vector relating to an observation point.)

Now it is convenient and therefore customary to summarize these $exp(\beta_i)$ in so called "rating tables", as, given an observation, they allow for a quick calculation of the expected frequency (or severity) that is furthermore easy to interprete.

Assuming independence between frequency and severity, you get the total amount by multiplying the two. Now since we have log link functions in both cases, we can easily get a rating table for the total amount by simply multiplying the entries in both tables (assuming both GLMs use the same variables of course). So here is where the questions begins:

Assuming I have $m$ different pairs of frequency and severity models and I want the sum of these, can I get a rating table for this? Or mathematically, assume random variables $F_i$, $S_i$ with $i=1,...,m$ that are modelled by GLMs as above, can I derive from those coefficients a multiplicative structure for $E[B]$ with $B = F_1\cdot S_1 + F_2\cdot S_2 + \dots + F_m\cdot S_m$?

I know I could just fit a model on this random variable $B$ and use a log link function, but can I also derive such a structure from the single models?

Of course, you don't have to stick to this insurance setting, a general answer will make me just as happy!

Comment: Usually in insurance, you don't really have such situation. The actuary aims at finding the best GLM model for the frequency and the best GLM model for the severity. Then, you can aggregate both components and get the premium. In your question, it is not clear what $F_i$ and $S_i$ represent. Are all $F_i$ identically distributed ? If so, summing up doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Well I could, for example, think of a situation where you want to model frequency and severity separately for different damage types (windscreen, collision, theft etc.) and then you would have to aggregate to get the total premium. In this case (as in my question) the F (frequencies) and S (severities) are not identically distributed.

Comment: I see. In this case, you can use the approach you proposed. The pure premium for the sum will then be the sum of the pure premiums for the different damages. However, if you want to measure the uncertainty via a Variance or Value at Risk, you will need to know the distribution of $B$ and therefore the dependence structure between the different damage types.

Comment: I see. But then I take it there is no (well-known) way to rigorously derive the coefficients of the whole model from the single parts (as described above)?